# How to create a spinner date picker(scrollable date-picker) in angular using predefined libraries or frameworks?

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-components, scrollable, nebular

[Click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olifA.png)
How to implement this in angular?